# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_URL failed to validate

Tags: php

trying to validate the url (https://www.demo) using the php, its pass the condition so strange.

I have added the code:

```
 $url = 'https://www.dsdsis';

 if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        echo($url ."is a valid URL");
    } else {
        echo($url ."is not a valid URL");
 }
```

its has to be invalid right?

Comment: Why does it have to be?

Comment: i am not exactly expert in URLs, but your $url example is pretty much valid url, you can read more about urls on [RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: I think they are asking because the TLD is missing in the uri

Comment: For reference http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396 is what FILTER_VALIDATE_URL validates against according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: `https://www.` this also pass the test :)

Answer (score 1):

It meets the criteria for the format of a valid URL. The filter does not actually test to see if the URL actually exists.

If you try your test without the protocol included, `http`, you will see that it fails. Add the protocol and any combination will be considered valid.